# ag-Grid React forgets gridApi after it has been set

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have modified the [Selection with Keys](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#example-selection-with-keyboard-arrow-keys) example to work with React. However as soon as I press an arrow key, the app crashes in the code below:

```js
const [gridApi, setGridApi] = useState<GridApi | undefined>();

const handleGridReady = (event: GridReadyEvent) => {
  setGridApi(event.api);
  setGridColumnApi(event.columnApi);
};

const keyboardNavigation = (params: NavigateToNextCellParams): CellPosition => {
    if (gridApi === undefined) {
        throw new Error('This should never happen!');
    }
    ...
};
```

I am setting `gridApi` using `onGridReady` before any keys are pressed (confirmed by adding a `console.log`). So I don't know how it is getting `undefined`.

My full source code is [here](https://github.com/nareshbhatia/trade-force/blob/master/trade-force-client/src/components/Orders/Orders.tsx#L80-L178).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState<GridApi | undefined>();

const onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
  setGridApi(params.api);
  setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
};

console.log(gridApi); // log the latest gridApi instance if re-render

const keyboardNavigation = (
  params: NavigateToNextCellParams
): CellPosition => {
  // always reference the first instance of gridApi
  if (gridApi === undefined) {
    throw new Error("This should always happen!");
  }
  ...
}
```

This is commonly known as *stale closure* in react hook. From my understanding here is what happen:

- Your callback `keyboardNavigation` is registered only once at the first render.
- `keyboardNavigation` at that time references the `gridApi` instance from the very first render which is `undefined`.
- `AgGridReact` in subsequent re-renders will use the first `keyboardNavigation` instance, thus references [the same old](https://whatthefuck.is/closure#a-ghost-of-a-function-call) `gridApi` even if it's been set now.

You can verify that by logging the `gridApi` in the render method, you can see from the second render, it has been initialized while your **closure** `keyboardNavigation` still references the **stale** instance of `gridApi`.

To fix that, you can change the code above to use reference instead of variable that can't be changed once baked in the closure.

```js
type AgGridApi = {
  grid?: GridApi;
  column?: ColumnApi;
};

...

const apiRef = React.useRef<AgGridApi>({
  grid: undefined,
  column: undefined
});
const api = apiRef.current;
const onGridReady = (params: GridReadyEvent) => {
  apiRef.current.grid = params.api;
  apiRef.current.column = params.columnApi;
};

const yourCallback = () => {
  api.grid?.doSomething()
  api.column?.doSomething()
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64071586/ag-grid-react-forgets-gridapi-after-it-has-been-set]

Comment: Wow, I could have never guessed this one! Thank you so much, Near. I implemented a minor variation that uses two useRefs instead of one: `const gridApiRef = useRef<GridApi>(); const columnApiRef = useRef<ColumnApi>();` That way I don't have to create a new type for both apis and also avoid the nested reference. The idea came from [this blog article](https://en.morzel.net/post/ag-grid-api-access-with-hooks).

Comment: @Naresh you're welcome. *Stale closure* is one of the common pitfalls in react hook, especially when you're switching from class-based component to functional component and start using hooks. Having a good mental model will help you identify the problem quicker. You can do that by reading more about how things work under the hood (in this case closure).