# React ag grid cellRendererFramework click and pass row data but state variable is Undefined

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I try to add delete button to my grid row, So I use cellRendererFramework and every thing is fine until state variable return undefined in my root component

I set my state variable with useEffect and every things seems to be OK and my grid shows data correctly

```
  let [roles, SetRoles] = React.useState<Role[]>();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    List().then((roles) => {
      console.log("set roles count:" + roles.data.length);
      SetRoles(roles.data);
    });
    return () => {
      console.error("Component will unmount!");
    };
  }, []);
```

**ColDefs defination:**

```
const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "کلید",
      field: "id",
      flex: 0,
      hide: true,
    },
    {
      headerName: "عنوان",
      field: "title",
      flex: 2,
      sortable: true,
      sort: "asc",
    },
    {
      headerName: "توضیحات جدید",
      field: "description",
      flex: 6,
    },
    {
      headerName: "حذف",
      field: "Id",
      flex: 1,
      cellRendererFramework: function (row: any) {
        return (
          <Button
            danger
            onClick={() => {
              onDeleteClick(row.data);
            }}
          >
            حذف
          </Button>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
```

and my onDeleteHandler and my **PROBLEM** is

```
  const onDeleteClick = (data: any) => {
    //this line works correctly and Id of my row pass to my event 
    console.log(data.id);
    //Issue is here, my loaded state variable in Undefined, But my other function like count of roles work correctly
    console.log(roles);
  };
```

[image: my data loads from controller and show in grid correctly]

[image: after click on delete button my row data pass correctly but get undefined for my state variable]

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64073988/9449426) for the explanation.

Comment: thanks, your suggestion helps me to find a new way of fixing a similar issue with react hooks

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        danger
        onClick={() => {
          onDeleteClick(row.data['id']);
        }}
      >
        حذف
</Button>
```